# how to xor a portion of code with objdump

Tags: x86, reverse-engineering, objdump

I want to xor a portion of code for a static analyse of a 32 bits elf executable.
I know the start and ending address, i know the xor key.

I tried to dump memory block with objdump and pipe it to a python script which make the xor.

But i am wondering if there is a fastest method in order to run the xor in bash script for example

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want `xor(_something_, _code_)` where _code_ is the output of running objdump?

Comment: yes that's it !